# Is it more efficient to have a table or an object?

Tags: performance, lua, lua-table

Would it be more memory-efficient, or more importantly, speed-efficient to use a table rather than an object? For reference, here is an example of the kind of table I'll be using.

[3, 4, 5, -1, 2, true, 32]

Or in object form:

{x1=3, y1=4, x2=5, y2=-1, GID=2, alive=true, LID=32}

As an extra, is it more efficient to have single-typed tables than to have multiple types like number and boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua only has tables. You may be talking about the distinction between the array part of a table and the key/value pair part. Lua does not have a *syntactic* distinction between these two things.

It is technically faster to access the array part of a table than the key/value pair part. *However*, unless you are writing high-performance code, and the code in question is within a "hot loop" that needs to execute hundreds of times per millisecond, you *should not care*. Write the code that makes it the most obvious what it is that you're doing. Write the code that is most appropriate to understand the algorithm.

If the "object form" makes it clearer to users what `some_obj.GID` is trying to access compared to the more opaque "table form" of `some_obj[5]`, then use the latter rather than the former. Unless you have actual performance metrics in hand, prefer the code that is easy to comprehend.

Comment: Alright, thanks very much. It's been a while since I used lua so I did forget that tables and objects are pretty much the same.